# merging Pandas data frame vertically not working properly

Tags: python, pandas

try to merge two pandas dataframes vertically but I am not able to merge it properly.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df1['cl1']=[1,2,3,4,5,3]
df1['cl2']=[2,3,4,5,6,3]
df1['cl3']=[5,4,3,2,1,4]

df2['clx']=[11,2,3,4,5]
df2['cly']=[22,3,4,5,6]
df2['clz']=[55,4,3,2,1]
df2['cla']=[66,4,3,2,1]
```

RESULT:

```
    cl1  cl2  cl3   clx   cly   clz   cla
0   1.0  2.0  5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   2.0  3.0  4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   3.0  4.0  3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   4.0  5.0  2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   5.0  6.0  1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5   3.0  3.0  4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0  22.0  55.0  66.0
7   NaN  NaN  NaN   2.0   3.0   4.0   4.0
8   NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0   4.0   3.0   3.0
9   NaN  NaN  NaN   4.0   5.0   2.0   2.0
10  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0   6.0   1.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using a custom merge function(work around).

```
 def merge_df(df1,df2):
    row_count1 = len(df1)
    row_count2 = len(df2)
    head_count1 = len(list(df1.columns))
    head_count2 = len(list(df2.columns))

    if head_count1 < head_count2:
        diff = head_count2 - head_count1
        for i in range(0, diff):
            df1[i] = [''] * row_count1
            df1.rename(columns={i:''},inplace=True)
    if head_count1 > head_count2:
        diff = head_count1 - head_count2
        for i in range(0, diff):
            df2[i] = [''] * row_count2
            df2.rename(columns={i: ''}, inplace=True)
    df1.loc[len(df1)] = list(df2.columns)
    for i in range(0,len(df2)):
        df1.loc[len(df1)] = list(df2.loc[i])
    return df1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) for set default `RangeIndex` to both `DataFrame`s and pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df1.set_axis(range(df1.shape[1]), axis=1), 
                 df2.set_axis(range(df2.shape[1]), axis=1)], 
                ignore_index=True)
print (out)
     0   1   2     3
0    1   2   5   NaN
1    2   3   4   NaN
2    3   4   3   NaN
3    4   5   2   NaN
4    5   6   1   NaN
5    3   3   4   NaN
6   11  22  55  66.0
7    2   3   4   4.0
8    3   4   3   3.0
9    4   5   2   2.0
10   5   6   1   1.0
```

If need also join columns names:

```
df11 = df1.set_axis(range(df1.shape[1]), axis=1)
df22 = df2.set_axis(range(df2.shape[1]), axis=1)
new = df11.columns.intersection(df22.columns)
                                
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df1.columns]),
                 df11, 
                 pd.DataFrame([df2.columns]),
                 df22], 
                ignore_index=True).reindex(new, axis=1)
print (out)
      0    1    2
0   cl1  cl2  cl3
1     1    2    5
2     2    3    4
3     3    4    3
4     4    5    2
5     5    6    1
6     3    3    4
7   clx  cly  clz
8    11   22   55
9     2    3    4
10    3    4    3
11    4    5    2
12    5    6    1
```